# A map $\alpha$ that induces a Vector Field over a Differential Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a differential manifold. Given a map $\alpha$ that is $C^{\infty}$,

$\alpha : \mathbb{R} \times M \to M$

such that

$\alpha(0,p) = p$

for every $p \in M$,

and

$\alpha(t,\alpha(s,p)) = \alpha(t+s, p) $

for every $p \in M$, $s,t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Show that $\alpha$ induces a vector field over $M$.

What I have done: I think this is cause $\alpha$ creates something like a curve on $M$ for every $p$, passing on $p$, thus for every point there is a direction, or a derivation.

Comment: This function $\alpha$ actually is a group action of $(\mathbb{R},+)$ on $M$, you can imagine it is an addition of real numbers with points in $M$, ie, $\alpha(t,p) = t+p$.

Comment: Your intuition is correct: take $X_p = \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} \alpha(t,p)$ for the induced vector field.

Comment: Thank you to both of you! @ZachEffman, is that expression meant to be in a chart? or? Something like: take a chart and pick $\alpha(t,p) = (\alpha_1(t), \alpha_2(t) \cdots)$ then derivate and calculate in $0$, then you get $(1,2,3)$, thus you get $d/dx + 2d/dy + 3d/dz$? I'm a little bit confused on how to express a vector field. I can give a map from the manifold to the tangent space, or a sum of the partial derivations, multiplied by functions, right?

Comment: Are you comfortable with differentials of maps between manifolds? If so, take $\alpha_p:\mathbb{R}\to M$ defined by $\alpha_p(t) = \alpha(t,p)$. Then the derivative above is $\alpha_{p*}(0)$. Your approach for evaluating  in coordinates is exactly correct.